# PHP end div after X amount of divs and start new one

Tags: php, html

I am trying to achieve to show 4 divs on 1 line and after those 4 divs it should automatically end the line and continue with the new line of 4 divs. What I have right now is;

```
            <?php
            // Make sure to just show items if there are any.
            if ($is_empty)
            {
                echo 'There are no products found.';
            }
            else
            {
                // Start counting the products.
                $i = 1;

                // List up all products.
                foreach ($results as $item):
                    // Count up the productcount.
                    $i++;
        ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/<?php echo $item['product_id']."-".$item['name_clean']; ?>.html">
                                <?php echo $item['name']; ?>
                            </a>
        <?php
                endforeach;
            }
        ?>
```

So like, if $i = 4, 8, 12 etc etc, cut off the line (maybe add a div that's holding those 4?) and start a new one.
Is that possible? I know it is with tables, as I found here [PHP: End and start a new <tr> after 6 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651368/php-end-and-start-a-new-tr-after-6-rows)

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of doing this in PHP, why not try doing it with CSS float and width properties?

Comment: You have no <div> in there. Do you mean lines of 4 <a> ?

Comment: This <a> will be inside a <div> once I got further with the website. It is going to contain images etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (%) to calculate every 4th element.

```
    <?php
            // Start counting the products.
            $i = 0;

            // List up all products.
            foreach ($results as $item):
                // Count up the productcount.
                $i++;
    ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/<?php echo $item['product_id']."-".$item['name_clean']; ?>.html">
                            <?php echo $item['name']; ?>
                        </a>
    <?php
                if($i%4 == 0):
    ?>
                        <br />
    <?php  
                endif;
    ?>
            endforeach;
    ?>
```