# MySQL php row values in horizontal format

Tags: php, html, css

Hello on my website I am fetching a list of data from a table.
For each item i am displaying it in a box.
The boxes are listed vertically.

I would like to view the boxes in a grid format with the boxes aligning horizontally side by side about 4 boxes across.

I am not sure if I need to do something with the MySQL commands in the while { } statement or if I can achieve this by using php.

The easiest way to expalin this is to show the page:

http://www.testphoto.fr/category.php?id=3

Here is some code:

```
while ($rowGetReviews = mysqli_fetch_array($reviewDetails))
{
echo '
<span>
<a href="productdetails.php?productid='.$rowGetReviews['ProductID'].'">
<section class="row reviewholder">
<img src="productimages/product_'.$rowGetReviews['ProductID'].'_image_1.jpg" width="260"  class="img-responsive">

<h4><a href="productdetails.php?productid='.$rowGetReviews['ProductID'].'">'.$rowGetReviews['ProductName'].'</a></h4>

<section class="averageholder">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"> </span>';
echo $rowGetReviews['Average'];
echo'</section>


</section>
</a>
<span>

';
}
```

CSS:

```
.reviewholder{
    background:#e0e0e0;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
        width:300px;
}
```

Many Thanks

Jean-Claude

Comment: Please add your code here. People are hesitant on clicking links. We need to see the code.

Comment: This is a php (or css) issue. Nothing to do with MySQL

Comment: This is a css problem.

Comment: Ok thankyou, any ideas on how to modify the php ?  Should I enter a for loop at the start of the while { } to split some of the code to make it horizontal

Comment: Ok if this is a css problem I'll include the css for row reviewholder in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

to fetch result row as an associative array use [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
using this only we can access with names ie; $rowGetReviews['ProductID']

[mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) used to get result in numeric array. here you need numeric key according to fetched columns order.say $rowGetReviews['2']

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($rowGetReviews = mysqli_fetch_array($reviewDetails))
{
echo '<div class=\"box\">';
echo '
<span>
<a href="productdetails.php?productid='.$rowGetReviews['ProductID'].'">
<section class="row reviewholder">
<img src="productimages/product_'.$rowGetReviews['ProductID'].'_image_1.jpg" width="260"  class="img-responsive">

<h4><a href="productdetails.php?productid='.$rowGetReviews['ProductID'].'">'.$rowGetReviews['ProductName'].'</a></h4>

<section class="averageholder">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"> </span>';
echo $rowGetReviews['Average'];
echo'</section>


</section>
</a>
</span></div>

';
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Using this code with the box <div> did not change the row format.  To get the rows in a horizontal format I am trying using a <table> and putting <table><tr> before the while{ } and the using a <td> at the beginning of each row item.

Comment: I am using some of the code found on this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651368/php-end-and-start-a-new-tr-after-6-rows